# CSS selector path for text box that comes immediately after h3 with text "Company Name"

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, capybara

Below is my html

```
<div class="right" data-bindattr-13="13">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
<div class="input-row">
<input id="ember4258" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text"/>
</div>
<h3>Full Company Legal Name</h3>
<div class="input-row">
<input id="ember4259" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text"/>
</div>
<h3>Company Phone</h3>
<div class="input-row">
<input id="ember4260" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text"/>
</div>
<h3>Federal Tax / Employer ID (EIN)</h3>
<div class="input-row">
<input id="ember4261" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Since class value off all the text fields and respective parent div **class** attributes are same  I need to fill these text fields without using nth-of-type.

I have done work around to create a CSS selector that should point the text box that is immediately after `<h3>Full Company Legal Name</h3>` .

**h3:contains(^Company Name$)+div>input**

But my Capybara script is not recognizing the above way and throwing the below error.

annotateInvalidSelectorError_': The given selector h3:contains(^Company Name$)+div>input is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Can any one provide a CSS that matches my requirement?

Regards,
Avinash Duggirala

Comment: Is one of the "Full Company Legal Name" h3 headings supposed to be "Company Name"? Otherwise, there does not appear to be a "Company Name" heading in the sample HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains` pseudo class was deprecated, which is why the InvalidSelectorError occurs. There is currently no way to check text nodes using CSS-selectors.

Instead, you can use XPath to traverse the DOM to sibling elements.

```
text_field = page.find(:xpath, '//h3[text() = "Company Name"]/following-sibling::div[1]/input')
text_field.set('some value')
```

Comment: Small typo , I am using capybara not watir.  <br/>

Provide some inputs on my workaround. Placing my views below  <br/>

page.all(:css, '.right>h3').each do |node|  <br/>
if node.text == "Company Name"  <br/>
# I need to append (+div>input) to the node and fill with required text. I need some inputs here regarding how to append (+div>input) to node  <br/>
end  <br/>
end  <br/>

Comment: I updated the example to use the Capybara API instead. I still think you will need to use XPath.

Comment: The above xpath is giving 4 matching nodes on the page and throwing the error "Ambiguous match, found 4 elements matching xpath "//h3[text() = \"Company Name\"]/following-sibling::div/input" (Capybara::Ambiguous)"

These are the test steps Justin
1. Enter www.zenefits.com
2. sign up #some dummy values
3. On home page Click on get quotes in the payroll box on upper left 
4. Then enter random number of employees say 2 and hit 'get quotes'
5.Select either payroll services.Click start

On this page I need to fill the text fields. Is my idea that I commented before worth of doing?

Comment: Sorry, missed a conversion when going from Watir to Capybara. Code fixed.

Comment: Super. Got 1 matching node now. As per my understanding achieving this through CSS is not possible , am I right?

Comment: To my knowledge, no, a pure CSS solution is not possible.